# Цикл FOR JAVASCRIPT. почему в конце выводится 3?

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста почему последний alert выводит именно 3??

let i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // используем существующую переменную
alert(i); // 0, 1, 2
}

alert(i); // 3, почему здесь 3????

Comment: очевидно же, что ваш цикл завершается при достижении переменной `i` значения `3`. вот вы его и наблюдаете после завершения цикла.

Comment: А что вы ожидали и почему? .............возьмите отладчик и посмотрите все шаги кода, в т..ч с заходом в цикл и итерированием по нему........ хотя можно чисто на листочке расписать всю логику

Comment: Я ожидал, что выведется 0, тк это  глобальная переменная, но почему это не так?

Comment: Потому что ты её изменяешь i++, какая разнице где ты её будешь изменять, она же глобальная. Локальную создают внутри for ( **let** i = 0; i < 3...